# unable to connect jQuery to HTML

Tags: jquery, html

ok this is what I want on my website:
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gCBcs)

the script is working on that site but not when I copied it and added to mysite.
I saved the jQuery in a file with .js and the HTML code to my webpage and also added

but its not working.. please help

Comment: What does your source look like on your page? Are you getting JS errors?

Comment: Are you using the right `href` to get your js file? What errors, if any, are in the js console?

Comment: Have you added jQuery or just the code at codepen?

Comment: I just tried it and it works, have you added `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Comment: What about checking your console???

Comment: Can't stress @roasted comment enough. The console will tell you everything you need to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you also included the **jQuery** library in your site?

Stick this above your other scripts in your page and see if it works:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hint: It helps when you post the rest of your code along with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use **jquery.min** file otherwise jquery not running.

Download the latest jquery from http://jquery.com/download/

Latest jquery
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
```